# Contradiction between $X^2_i/n\overset{P}{\to}0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^nX^2_i/n\overset{P}{\to}\sigma^2$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, random-variables

## Setup

Let random variables $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ be i.i.d. $N(0, \sigma^2)$.

## What I know

By Chebyshev's inequality,
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X^2_i \overset{P}{\to} \sigma^2.
$$
On the other hand, since
$$
\mathbb E\left[\left(\frac{1}{n}X^2_i - 0\right)^2\right] = \frac{1}{n^2}\mathbb E[X^4_i] = \frac{3\sigma^4}{n^2} \to 0,
$$
we get
$$
\frac{1}{n}X^2_i \overset{P}{\to} 0 \text{ for all }i = 1, \ldots, n.
$$

## Problem

One contradiction arises here.

In general, it is known following theorem: If $A_n$ and $B_n$ are two sequences of random variables satisfying
$$
A_n \overset{P}{\to} a \text{ and } B_n \overset{P}{\to} b
$$
respectively, then
$$
A_n + B_n \overset{P}{\to} a + b.
$$
So, using this theorem,
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X^2_i = \frac{1}{n}X^2_1 + \cdots \frac{1}{n}X^2_n \overset{P}{\to} 0 \neq \sigma^2.
$$

What is wrong? Or is my description correct?

Comment: there is no contradiction : the theorem you quote applies for a finite sum, not a sum where the number of summands goes to infinity...

Comment: Even in real analysis you have $\frac{\sigma}{n} \to 0$ , but $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sigma}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n i =\sigma$$ for any $\sigma \ne 0$